# How to format the title in \begin{thebibliography} \end{thebibliography} for a list of about 15 entries

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

```
%
%---------------------------------- %
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%---------------------------------- %
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm} %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{libertine} %

\begin{document}

\noindent How can I format the title "Bibliography" below

with say, libertineSB, fontsize {12}, {14}\hspace{1.4pt}?

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent There will be about 15 book titles in the list.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem {ref_01} Author 1\hspace{1.1pt}; \hspace{2.0pt}Book 1\hspace{0.7pt},  \hspace{1.0pt}first edition, 2018\hspace{1.0pt}.

\bibitem {ref_02} Author 2\hspace{1.1pt}; \hspace{2.0pt}Book 2\hspace{0.7pt},  \hspace{1.0pt}first edition, 2020\hspace{1.0pt}.

\bibitem {ref_03} Author 3\hspace{1.1pt}; \hspace{2.0pt}Book 3\hspace{0.7pt},  \hspace{1.0pt}first edition, 2022\hspace{1.0pt}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is `\chapter*{\bibname}%` so just format used for unnumbered chapters which you can define directly or using `titlesec` that you are already using

Comment: David Carlisle@ I guessed that \bibname defaults to \bibliography and so I inserted \chapter*{\bibliography}% in the preamble? It gives an error.  Could you amend my MWE with your solution, please?

Comment: you have no question here at all, you ask how to format the bibliography heading which is a chapter title, but you have not said what  changes you want to make. ` I guessed that \bibname defaults to \bibliography ` no just the word `Bibliography` not the command, but as far as I can tell you do not need that at all, just specify how you want chapter headings laid out. Why does having 15 entries affect the heading at all???

Comment: David Carlisle@ on the last point... I thought I'd offer the number 15 as I've seen the parameters {9} and {99} mentioned as relevant in other Stack Exchange answers.

Comment: David Carlisle@ I can format my chapter headings by imitating others, but how is that utilizes in this case - do I need an entry in the preamble.  I am not at all well-versed in these matters.

Comment: sorry I really can not guess your question here, how do you want to format chapters? Do not format this heading differently. What is wrong with the format it has now?

Comment: The syntax \begin{thebibliography}... \end{\thebibliography} produces a heading for the table of references - presumably using some kind of \bibliographystyle file.  A simple version of the makeup of that file is, I think, what I need.

Comment: no look in book.cls as I say the heading is smply `\chapter*{Bibliography}` so to style that just style your chapter headings, not anything specific for biblographies. `\bibliographystyle` is for bibtex styles but you are not using bibtex

Comment: Add a \renewcommand as in "answer my own question" appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

\renewcommand{\bibname}{\libertineSB{\fontsize{12.25}{15}\selectfont{References\vspace{3.2pt}}}}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

Comment: Please, give an explanation of your code so others can benefit from your answer. In the question title the OP asks for about 15 entries, but `\begin{thebibliography}{10}` is 10 entries.

Comment: @LuisTurcio it is a self-answered question, so the answerer is the OP and this answer works for him. I do agree though that some more explanation (and code formatting) would be helpful in making this answer more useful for future visitors.

Comment: I do not know how to incorporate my answer into my original MWE on this site.  I would be pleased if someone else would do that on my behalf.   It only means replacing one line of code with two modified lines.  Regarding the 15 entries...  can someone explain why values {9}, {10} and {99} are variously used in this context, but hardly ever, any others.